# How can I statically link Arrow when building parquet-cpp?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, parquet

From the [parquet-cpp home page](https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp):

> By default, Parquet links to Arrow's shared libraries. If you wish to statically-link the Arrow symbols instead, pass -DPARQUET_ARROW_LINKAGE=static.

I do want to statically link Arrow, because I want to use my program on other servers that won't have Arrow installed.  I tried `-DPARQUET_ARROW_LINKAGE=static`, but I get an error about "missing transitive dependencies":

```
# cmake -DPARQUET_BUILD_TESTS=Off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPARQUET_MINIMAL_DEPENDENCY=ON -DPARQUET_ARROW_LINKAGE=static .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
...
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1717 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
...
-- THRIFT_HOME:
-- Thrift compiler/libraries NOT found:  (THRIFT_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND, THRIFT_STATIC_LIB-NOTFOUND). Looked in system search paths.
-- Thrift include dir: /root/tmp/parquet-cpp-master/thrift_ep/src/thrift_ep-install/include
-- Thrift static library: /root/tmp/parquet-cpp-master/thrift_ep/src/thrift_ep-install/lib/libthrift.a
-- Thrift compiler: /root/tmp/parquet-cpp-master/thrift_ep/src/thrift_ep-install/bin/thrift
-- Checking for module 'arrow'
--   No package 'arrow' found
-- Could not find the Arrow library. Looked for headers in , and for libs in
-- Building Apache Arrow from commit: 501d60e918bd4d10c429ab34e0b8e8a87dffb732
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wall -std=c++11
-- Found cpplint executable at /root/tmp/parquet-cpp-master/build-support/cpplint.py
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:515 (message):
  Missing transitive dependencies for Arrow static linking
```

So I [found the code](https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L506) that generates the error:

```
  if (NOT DEFINED ENV{BROTLI_STATIC_LIB_ENC} OR
      NOT DEFINED ENV{BROTLI_STATIC_LIB_DEC} OR
      NOT DEFINED ENV{BROTLI_STATIC_LIB_COMMON} OR
      NOT DEFINED ENV{SNAPPY_STATIC_LIB} OR
      NOT DEFINED ENV{ZLIB_STATIC_LIB} OR
      NOT DEFINED ENV{LZ4_STATIC_LIB} OR
      NOT DEFINED ENV{ZSTD_STATIC_LIB})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Missing transitive dependencies for Arrow static linking")
```

But that doesn't really help me, since I don't know what to do to get those environment variable defined.

Do I need to compile Arrow and install myself first?  (I would rather have parquet-cpp do it for me.)

Comment: At least right off, it looks like you need to [install Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/cpp) (and possibly build the static version of its libraries).

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin, but when I previously did a build with Arrow linkage set to `shared` instead of `static`, I saw the same messages about Thrift libraries not found.  When I then ran `make` (which is the next step after running `cmake`), it pulled down and compiled the needed thrift stuff.  This first step is just setting up the build files.  So I assume I can safely ignore the messages about missing Thrift libraries.

Comment: Okay, fair enough (might not hurt to clarify that in the question though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I arranged a script to download dependencies sources, set the environment variables and run your `cmake` line at the end. Just change the DEPDIR variable value, setting it to a directory of choice.

```
#!/bin/bash

CMKDIR=$PWD
DEPDIR=/tmp

cd $DEPDIR

#snappy
git clone https://github.com/google/snappy.git
cd snappy
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake ..
make

export SNAPPY_STATIC_LIB=$DEPDIR/snappy/build/libsnappy.a

cd $DEPDIR

#brotli
git clone https://github.com/google/brotli.git
cd brotli
mkdir out
cd out
../configure-cmake
make

export BROTLI_STATIC_LIB_ENC=$DEPDIR/brotli/out/libbrotlienc-static.a
export BROTLI_STATIC_LIB_DEC=$DEPDIR/brotli/out/libbrotlidec-static.a
export BROTLI_STATIC_LIB_COMMON=$DEPDIR/brotli/out/libbrotlicommon-static.a

cd $DEPDIR

#zlib
git clone https://github.com/madler/zlib.git
cd zlib
./configure
make

export ZLIB_STATIC_LIB=$DEPDIR/zlib/libz.a

cd $DEPDIR

#lz4
git clone https://github.com/lz4/lz4.git
cd lz4
make

export LZ4_STATIC_LIB=$DEPDIR/lz4/lib/liblz4.a

cd $DEPDIR

#zstd
git clone https://github.com/facebook/zstd.git
cd zstd
make

export ZSTD_STATIC_LIB=$DEPDIR/zstd/lib/libzstd.a

cd $CMKDIR

cmake -DPARQUET_BUILD_TESTS=Off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPARQUET_MINIMAL_DEPENDENCY=ON -DPARQUET_ARROW_LINKAGE=static
```

This script is very simple but should be effective. Just copy it in a new file (in the same CMakeLists.txt directory), give the file the execute permissions (i.e. `sudo chmod +x filename`) and execute it like this:

```
./filename.sh
```

About the **fPIC option issue**, you have to edit some files:

*snappy*: add this line in CMakeLists.txt, at the beginning, after the first two lines:

```
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

*lz4* and *zstd*: edit the Makefile in lib sub-directory, after this line

```
CFLAGS  += $(DEBUGFLAGS) $(MOREFLAGS)
```

add this line:

```
CFLAGS += -fPIC
```

*zlib*: edit the Makefile, after this line

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN
```

add this line:

```
CFLAGS += -fPIC
```

*brotli*: as far as I can see from make output, the option is already set.

Before running make again, execute this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEPDIR=/tmp

cd $DEPDIR/snappy/build
cmake ..
make clean
make

cd $DEPDIR/lz4
make clean
make

cd $DEPDIR/zstd
make clean
make
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It almost worked.  I need to compile the dependencies with `-fPIC`: `/bin/ld: /tmp/snappy/build/libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`.  Would you know how to add this compilation flag to each of the above dependencies?

Comment: Hi @MarkRajcok, I edited the answer to address the -fPIC issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to also modify the zlib Makefile (I edited your answer).